# Windows 10 Boot Menu access hot key?

Tags: windows-10, boot, hotkeys, asus-laptop

With an [Asus N56JN](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N56JN/specifications/), I'm trying to boot into the advanced set up menu using a hotkey.

I've done it once successfully with `ESC` but I'm not able to reproduce it.

I've disabled fast boot and secure boot. and can access the menu by booting  into Windows 10 and then restarting from the settings menu but I'd like to be able to go directly into advanced startup using a hotkey.

The [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/N56JN/E6951.pdf) implies either `F2` or `ESC` should do the trick but doesn't indicate exactly when to hit the key.

Additionally, I've replaced the original hard drive with an SSD so boot times are much faster maybe giving me a tighter window for hitting the key?

Any suggestions for the procedure are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Start tapping ESC as soon as you power up. Keep tapping until you see the boot menu.

Comment: yeah that has worked for me once out of maybe 10 tries, It occurred to me that maybe I'm hitting ESC, entering the menu without the screen updating, and then hitting ESC again to leave the menu and continuing into Windows 10 without ever seeing the boot menu? Is it very consistently successful for you or occasionally doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I've continued experimenting with things for a while with no luck.

Ended up using the windows utility for booting into the advanced startup menu as detailed [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21756-boot-usb-drive-windows-10-pc.html).

Now that I have GRUB installed, the hotkey is not necessary.